# Installing Windows 7 on Dell Optiplex 745

Tags: windows-7, windows, intel-core2, intel-pentium, dell-optiplex

I have 2x Dell Optiplex 745 machines, each with a slightly different spec.

**1st machine**

- Core 2 Duo @ 1.86 GHz
- 2 GB RAM
- 250GB HDD

**2nd machine**

- Pentium D @ 3.0 GHz
- 1 GB RAM
- 250GB HDD

I have successfully installed Windows 7 on the machine with the Pentium D CPU, first time, with no problems!

The machine with the Core 2 Duo is being very problematic, and other users have been experiencing the same thing!

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried anything besides install? Wipe the drive for example? I have dozens of those with the Core 2 Duo running 7.

Comment: @AthomSfere, WD Blue 250GB full wipe, fresh install...no luck! :-(

Comment: "problematic" how exactly?

Comment: @Karan, hangs half way through setup. If you google Optiplex 745 Windows 7 blank screen, you'll find out...it's not just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely causes I have experienced with the C2 Duo 745's are:

1. Hard drive: Zero the drive or swap and test
2. Bad caps on the motherboard, especially the caps with an "Y", the "K" caps do much better.

If you have wiped the drive, try a new drive or the one from the D just to see what happens.

Also, look at the motherboard carefully. Any bulging or leaking capacitors?
The Y caps look like this:
[image]

Comment: Bulging caps...yes...on both machines. What does this indicate?

Comment: Capacitors are one of the elements that regulate your power in the PC. It means that there will likely be varying issues with the machine.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor Thats info on caps. 

If you know how to solder, they can be replaced cheaply, if not its equivalent to a failed motherboard. The machines will never be reliable with bad caps.

Comment: Hmmmm...never experienced problems with caps on these machines before. I used to work as an I.T technician and worked with these machines, along with GX520 and 755 models too.

Comment: It's strange as the PC works fine with Windows XP, just not 7. In terms of caps, yes I could change them...I've heard that Jap caps are better.

Comment: The GX 280 and the 745s were the worst for some reason. And I can't say why exactly, but the 745s have a hard time with imaging properly with bad caps. The 755, 760's used very different caps then the 745 and hold out much better

Comment: Think its faulty motherboard. IYE, will an OptiPlex 755 board fit in a 745 case?

Comment: As long as you stay within a form factor, yes. We have mostly SFF (Small form factor) and everything is interchangeable with the 745 / 755 / 760 and same with our ATX size ones. Just make sure you stay with the same form factor and should not be an issue

Comment: I might try changing the caps first as I have some experience of electronic maintenance and will be less costly...sure enough...my caps are bulging/leaking!